# GCC ignoring the "access" function-attribute?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

I am currently getting into using attributes using c. However when trying to use the "access" attribute for funtions. However when compiling I get a warning saying the attribute is ignored.

This is a minimal example that has this issue arise:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__ ((access (read_only,1))) void  printAll(double * arr,size_t size){
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++) printf("%lf\n", arr[i]);
}

int main(){
  double testArr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
  printAll(testArr,6);
}
```

The compiler gives the following warning:

`warning: 'access' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes] __attribute__ ((access (read_only,1))) void  printAll(double * arr,size_t size){`

I read about this issue arising with other attributes.
And one solution was that the gcc version may be relevant.
I still have gcc version 8.3.0 from an older installation.

Comment: Done! The issue still arises though (same warning).

Comment: yeah, just checked. `const` doesn't help

Comment: FWIW, the same warning persists up to version 9.5 of `gcc` and is gone in v10.1 and up

Comment: So it is version dependent... Apperently the access attribute was first added in 10.1. Thanks for the help!